# Does Euclidean metric imply the space is flat ? Incidence on quantum relativity?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question

If the metric at each point of space were $$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$

Does it imply this space is flat and that the geodesics are straight lines ?

My guess is no, since the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be embedded in a 8 dimensional space which has a finite hypervolume.

In fact to have an information about curvedeness one need to compute the projection between two distants triad, (or tetrad in general relativity).

Could one for example find an equation for a bilocal metric given at two points separated by Planck length ? Then putting in the Einstein Field equation the metric $$g_{\mu\nu}=\langle \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x^\mu}(x)|\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x^\nu}(x+v_{Planck})\rangle$$

,Where $v_{Planck}$ is a vector of Planck's length $\sqrt{\hbar G/c^3}$,

Should give an equation containing h,G and c, hence a quantum gravitational equation ?

Comment: What is the definition of "flat space" and "geodesics are  straight lines", and how would that embedding contradict it?

Comment: I thought how could infinite straight lines be put in a finite hypervolume ? But this makes no point since those can be simply circles. The second point is also not consistent since for example in polar coordinates the basis along theta is rotating but the plane is flat.

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong to physics.se ?